# Error on migrating from .NET Framework 1.0 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, migration

I have a application which was Developed on .NET Framework 1.0 and I migrated it to .NET Framework 4.5

So I am getting this error on visual studio 2015

> HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
>   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes:
>   This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.

I convert the .net Framework by the application property

Comment: did u convert the code using VS, and address all the conversion errors reported by VS?

Comment: Yes I did when I  open the application in VS it ask me to convert it.. And then It convert it and then from the application property I change the framework to 4.0 but start getting error 500.23, the thing is that I have to work on VS after that I will think to upload on IIS but it showing error on VS

Comment: if u upgraded it through VS, u don't need to change anything at all, unless there is a custom setting by the app design.